# Restore activity data on clicking back button

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

On Activity 1 I have EditText and Button. On clicking the button Activity 2 loads:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

It is configured to have Activity 1 as parent:

```
<activity android:name=".Activity2" android:parentActivityName=".Activity1" >
    <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value="com.domain.app.Activity1" />
</activity>
```

When I click back button on Activity 2, the text entered by user in edit field is lost. How can I restore it?

I tried `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` on Activity 1 but it doesn't work (`onRestoreInstanceState` is never called).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you don't confuse "back" with "up". Up navigation is not the same thing as the bottom-left or physical back button. It recreates the up Activity by default, unless you set the launch mode to "singleTop" for the up Activity in the manifest.

Comment: And this is the best answer, I came from iOS world and still keep forgetting that there is Back button… Any hint how to make the Up button to behave the same as Back button?

Comment: To make the up button act as back, just override  onOptionsItemSelected() in the Activity to handle the menu item with id android.R.id.home and call finish().

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the sharedPreferences class to store the data temporarily. This may involve having another button to load the sharedpreferences data after returning to activity1. All the best.